# Sails.js handling attribute validation errors

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails-mongo

In [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) it is possible to use different database connections for models and it is easy to change database (MySQL or MongoDB). The problem arises when I want to display validation errors. These are my codes:

Groups.js model

```
...
    connection: 'MysqlConnection', //or connection: 'MongodbConnection'
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        },
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
...
```

GroupsController.js controller:

```
...
//add group to database
Groups.create(group, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send('Error'); // is it possible to send only validation error
        return;
    } else {
        res.send(data);
    }
});
...
```

Should I handle each attribute validation error separately, is it possible to send only validation error?

MySQL returns:

```
Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid ...
```

MongoDB returns:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem. You can make console.log(req.params.all()); and show what is wrong. In my case, id is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
      Model.catch(function(err) {
        var inspect = Object.keys(err)// [ "reason","invalidAttributes", ".."        ]
        console.log(  Object.keys(err.invalidAttributes) ) // ["name","etc.."]
      })
```

to catch the error